Connection between inference rule and Tautology
In the book A Profile of Mathematical Logic from Howard DeLong in § 16, Primary logic, the Propositional calculus, I noticed two teachings quoted below:

To each valid argument there corresponds a true conditional statement in which the antecedent is a conjunction of the premisses and the consequent is the conclusion.


An argument in the propositional calculus is valid if and only if its corresponding conditional proposition is a tautology.

Inference rules, Modus Ponens (transformation rule), Modus Tollens, Hypothetical Syllogism, Disjunctive Syllogism are some classical arguments. They need to have primarily true conclusion when the premises are true.
So, If there is such a rule but it's not tautological, it needs to work fine.
As an example DeLong shows by Truth Tables that the conditional corresponding proposition is a Tautology.

an example from Chrysippus. Either the first or the second or the third. Not the first. Not the second. Therefore the third.

I will write (in a manner easy to write since I cannot draw a Table. I wrote step by step from left to right) the Truth Table.
D5 = ((((p V q) V r) ∧ (~p)) ∧ (~q)) ⊃ r
D1 = p ∨ q
D2 = (p ∨ q) ∨ r
D3 = ((p ∨ q) ∨ r) ∧ ~p
D4 =  (((p ∨ q) ∨ r) ∧ ~p) ∧ ~q



P
q
r
D1
D2
D3
D4
D5




T
T
T
T
T
F
F
T


T
T
F
T
T
F
F
T


T
F
T
T
T
F
F
T


T
F
F
T
T
F
F
T


F
T
T
T
T
T
F
T


F
T
F
T
T
T
F
T


F
F
T
F
T
T
T
T


F
F
F
F
F
F
F
T



The line 7 shows that when p is false and q is false and r is true, D5 is true. This line is needed. But why is it needed that the 8 lines (wrote and numbered above in my kind of table) show D5 formula is true.
I'm sure it's not a coincidence.
To me it seems that the fact that the the rule-corresponding proposition is a Tautology is not logically linked to being a Theorem.
I guess that the Truth Tables is a competing method. And when we have a Tautology D5, the only way to get the line 7 is to make 'r' true.
So, it seems to me that deduction (Syntax) and Truth Tables (Semantic) are two methods connected. I don't understand the connection between them. I further learned that this has to do with Completeness (to reach all the Tautologies through deduction) and consistency (to deduct only Tautologies) of the Propositional Calculus.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks so much. Now I understand that Tautology is to say that the reasoning of the logician, which has a conditional form, is logically true. Perhaps is it the core of the deduction theorem. By the way I ask myself if to speak about Tautology is not meta of meta language.

In first-order logic "__ is a tautology" can not itself be expressed. Something is a tautology if it is true in all models (all interpretations, all possible truth-assigments) of the theory), so you would be using a meta-language or a second-order logic to express the concept of tautology. "T ⊢ p" or "⊢ p" (expressing that p can be derived in T) is also not part of first-order logic.

In the example you have given, there are three premises and a conclusion. Following your notation, if we use p for 'the first', q for 'the second' and r for 'the third' then the argument may be stated as:
1. p ∨ q ∨ r  
2. ¬p 
3. ¬q 
4. Therefore, r.

This argument is valid and we could prove that using natural deduction rules or an axiom system. But in the case of the classical propositional calculus we have another option, which is to use truth tables.
In classical propositional logic, the material conditional obeys the deduction theorem, so we have the following:
Γ, A ⊢ B        if and only if      Γ ⊢ A → B

Here, Γ denotes a set of propositions, which we can think of as the premises of an argument, A and B are propositions, ⊢ indicates derivability and → is the material conditional. So this equivalence says that if Γ together with A prove B, then Γ proves the material conditional A → B. By iteration, we can take all the propositions from within Γ, and move them over to the right of the turnstile and make them antecedents of the material conditional.
So, for example,
A, B, C ⊢ D      
A, B ⊢ C → D 
A ⊢ B → (C → D)  
⊢ A → (B → (C → D)) 

which in turn is logically equivalent to
⊢ (A ∧ B ∧ C) → D

Hence we have the relationship that you quote from DeLong. The argument "A, B, C therefore D" is valid if and only if the corresponding conditional sentence "(A ∧ B ∧ C) → D" is a tautology. Now all we have to do is construct a truth table for the conditional sentence and check whether it is a tautology. It is a tautology if a T appears in every row, i.e. it is true under all valuations. The example from Chrysippus looks like this:
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| p | q | r | ((p ∨ q ∨ r) ∧ ¬p ∧ ¬q) → r  |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| F | F | F |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| F | F | T |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| F | T | F |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| F | T | T |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| T | F | F |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| T | F | T |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| T | T | F |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+
| T | T | T |         T                     |
+---+---+---+-------------------------------+

So we know that the conditional sentence is a tautology and the argument is valid.

Thanks so much. Maybe I begin to understand. The drivability "from nothing" is a non conditioned truth called Logical Truth. So, as Mauro Allegranza commented and you answered, the deduction Axioma is the root of the answer. When you observe the whole reason of the logician, you see that this reasoning is logic. This is a conditional which is logically true. In other words a Tautology. Thanks to you and to Mauro.

An argument (in the propositional calculus) consists of several antecendents and a conclusion. The antecendents can all be grouped together into one conjunction. Then the argument has the form

p
---
q

Or p ⊢ q, which says that q can be validly inferred from p (by applying some inference rules).
The "corresponding conditional" in this case is "p → q". This last proposition needs to be a tautology, in order for the original argument to be valid. (So, p, the antecent, by itself does not need to be a tautology.)
In the example you quoted, you can see that the complete sentence is always true, no matter what the truth-values of its components are. This also shows that it is a tautology (a statement that is true for any possible assignment of truth-values to its component propositions, or a statement that is true in all possible models, i.e. for all possible interpretations).

I'm trying to understand you answer

@kouty - Bumble's answer below spells everything out with more clarity and detail.

Thank you for your answer.

A conditional is false IFF its antecedent is true and the consequent is false.
For a valid argument, it is never the case that the premises are true and the conclusion is false.
What happens when we construct "the corresponding conditional" for the valid argument below (P for premise):
P1
P2
.
.
.
Pn
Ergo ...
Conclusion C
?
The "corresponding conditional":
(P1 ∧ P2 ∧ ... ∧ Pn) → C
The antecedent could be false if any of the premises is false. The consequent could be true or false. Such a conditional always evaluates to true.
The antecedent could be true (none of the premises are false). We know the argument is valid and so the consequent has to be true. Such a conditional always evaluates to true.
The "corresponding conditional" (for a valid argument), therefore, is a tautology (always true).

The answer seems to be that the syntactic statement "D5 = ((((p V q) V r) ∧ (~p)) ∧ (~q)) ⊃ r", when examined semantically as an Object Language statement, is obviously a Tautology, because it expresses a Logical Truth.

Connected to this post
